# Possible to paint to window in NSIS, How to declare WinAPI variable of type?

Tags: winapi, nsis

Is it possible to paint to a Static control in NSIS? If it is how do I go about declaring variables such as a `PAINTSTRUCT` and etc? I can do this easily in regular C but using NSIS and the assembly type language is throwing me.

Below I'm trying to draw a border on a static control:

```
Var MainWndSubProc
Function MainWndSubProc
    ${If} $2 = ${WM_DRAWITEM}
        # I'm assuming $3 = the WPARAM and $4 = LPARAM?

        $LOWORD $R0 $3 # get id of window we are painting
        ${If} $R0 == $myStaticId
            # C code which works: how to translate to NSIS 'assembly'?
            HDC hdc;
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            hdc = BeginPaint(args.hwnd, &ps);

            RECT mRect;
            GetClientRect(args.hwnd, &mRect);

            HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(50, 50, 50));
            HPEN pen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 5, RGB(191, 191, 191));
            SelectObject(hdc, pen);
            SelectObject(hdc, brush);
            Rectangle(hdc, 0, 0, mRect.right, mRect.bottom);
            DeleteObject(pen);
            DeleteObject(brush);

            EndPaint(args.hwnd, &ps);


            # NSIS translation
            # how to declare PAINTSTRUCT
            $LOWORD $R0 $4
            System::Call `user32::BeginPaint(i $R0, i R1)`
            .. ?
        ${EndIf}
    ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Function MyGUIInit
    ${WndSubclass_Subclass} $HWNDPARENT MainWndSubProc $MainWndSubProc $MainWndSubProc
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Digging through their documentation I couldn't see anything about it, but their documentation site does have [several complete installers](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Category:Real_World_Installers) which may do it. The [WndSubclass](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/WndSubclass_plug-in) plug-in may have the functionality that you need, but I doubt it. All things being equal, if it were my project, I'd probably just write a plugin that does all of the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Types <= 64-bit are stored as strings in normal NSIS variables. For larger types you need to use the system plug-in struct syntax:

```
OutFile test.exe
RequestExecutionLevel user

Page InstFiles

!include WinMessages.nsh
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include Colors.nsh
!include WndSubclass.nsh

Var MainWndSubProc
Var hStaticCtrl
Function MainWndSubProc
${If} $2 = ${WM_DRAWITEM}
    System::Call '*$4(i,i,i,i,i,i.r5,i.r6,i,i,i.r8,i.r9)' ; Get HWND, HDC and size from DRAWITEMSTRUCT
    ${If} $hStaticCtrl = $5
        System::Call 'GDI32::CreateSolidBrush(i 0x2277ee)i.s' ; Just made up a color here
        System::Call 'GDI32::SelectObject(ir6,is)i.s'
        ${RGB} $7 191 191 191
        System::Call 'GDI32::CreatePen(i${PS_SOLID}, i5, i "0x$7")i.s'
        System::Call 'GDI32::SelectObject(ir6,is)i.s'
        System::Call 'GDI32::Rectangle(ir6, i0, i0, ir8, ir9)'
        System::Call 'GDI32::SelectObject(ir6,is)i.s'
        System::Call 'GDI32::DeleteObject(is)'
        System::Call 'GDI32::SelectObject(ir6,is)i.s'
        System::Call 'GDI32::DeleteObject(is)'
    ${EndIf}
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Function .onGUIInit
; Your example failed to show how you create the static control so I'm forced to just create one here at run-time
GetDlgItem $0 $hwndparent 2 ; Find cancel button so we can put our control there
ShowWindow $0 0
System::Call '*(i,i,i,i)i.r1'
System::Call 'USER32::GetWindowRect(ir0,ir1)'
System::Call 'USER32::MapWindowPoints(i0,i$hwndparent,ir1,i2)'
System::Call '*$1(i.r4,i.r5,i.r6,i.r7)'
System::Free $1
IntOp $6 $6 - $4
IntOp $7 $7 - $5
System::Call 'USER32::CreateWindowEx(i0, t "Static", i0, i${WS_CHILD}|${WS_VISIBLE}|${SS_OWNERDRAW}, ir4, ir5, ir6, ir7, i$hwndparent, i0, i0, i0)i.r0'
StrCpy $hStaticCtrl $0
${WndSubclass_Subclass} $HWNDPARENT MainWndSubProc $MainWndSubProc $MainWndSubProc
FunctionEnd

Section
SectionEnd
```

The quality of your C code leads me to believe that you are not ready to write this kind of code. If you look at the documentation for [DRAWITEMSTRUCT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775802%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) you will see this comment for the hDC member: "this device context **must** be used when performing drawing operations on the control." but you decided to call `BeginPaint`! You also fail to restore the DC and you delete objects that are selected into a DC and that is not allowed.

Comment: thanks, yes I copied my code from my WinAPI project that handles `WM_PAINT` not `WM_DRAWITEM`. Re releasing the DC, is that required in `WM_PAINT` aswell?

Comment: re the static control I will be painting, its an existing Static control `$mui.WelcomePage.title`. I've added the `SS_OWNERDRAWN` style to it and confirmed it succeeded using WinSpy. But it's not drawing the border on this control. Any idea what could be the error?

Comment: You only have to release the DC if you call a function to get it in the first place. You might have to remove other SS_* styles if any.